Toml++ conversion to vector<int>(C++)
Imagine I have a .toml containing this:
[Calculator_parameters]
dontVary = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

How do I process this into a vector to send over an MPI interface with toml++ (https://marzer.github.io/tomlplusplus/index.html)?
I tried something along the lines of:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // Include for file stream operations
#include "toml.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    toml::table tbl;
    tbl = toml::parse(file);  // file is some string that I get from user input. This part works for sure.
    ...
    auto dontVary_array = tbl["Calculator_parameters"]["dontVary"];  
    vector<int> dontVary;
    if (toml::array* arr = dontVary_array.as_array()) {
        arr->for_each([&dontVary](auto&& el)
        {
            if (const auto* int_elem = el.as_integer())
                dontVary.push_back((int)(*int_elem));          //Type mismatch somewhere here???         
            else
                cerr << "Error: Element is not an integer." << endl;
        });
    

Generally, there appears to be some type mismatch and I have trouble resolving it.
Thanks in advance for your help.
I expected to convert the tom_array into a C++ vector of ints.

Please remove the cast (int)(*int_elem) and include the full error message in the question.

C-style casts can hide the underlying error ( which is why they are dangerous ).

Error without the cast:  no matching member function for call to 'push_back' dontVary.push_back((*int_elem));

Try: dontVary.push_back((int)(int_elem->ref<int64_t>()));. BTW - I agree it is better to do it without the cast, which is trivial if dontVary is a vector<int64_t>.

@wohlstad the error now is error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'ref' as a dependent template name dontVary.push_back((int)(int_elem->ref<int64_t>())). The underlying type is int64_t, but I am not sure this can be easily send via MPI

What compiler and version of C++ are you using ? (the line I posted compiles on MSVC with C++20).

I compile on a AlmaLinux 9.3 cluster via mpiicpx (intel 2024.0.2)

If anybody is interested, this solves the issue, but may cause bugs down the line, so I would still be interested in a cleaner solution:
auto dontVary_array = tbl["Calculator_parameters"]["dontVary"];
vector<int> dontVary;
if (toml::array* arr = dontVary_array.as_array()) {
    arr->for_each([&dontVary](auto&& el)
    {
        if (const auto* int_elem = el.as_integer()) {
            long int v = (long int)(*int_elem);
            dontVary.push_back(v);
        }
        else
            cerr << "Error: Element is not an integer." << endl;
    });


If the code needs the cast to (long int) then there is probably still an underlying issue that needs to be looked into.  Prefer static_cast<long int>(*int_elem); if a cast is needed.

I could solve it differently in my code, but this solution is problem specific.

The following code might be helpful. I use them in my project.
const auto& dontVary_array = tbl["Calculator_parameters"]["dontVary"];

std::vector<int> dontVary;

if (dontVary_array.is_array())
{
    for (auto iter = dontVary_array.as_array()->begin(); iter < dontVary_array.as_array()->end(); ++iter)
    {
        dontVary.emplace_back( static_cast<int>( iter->as_integer()->get() ) );
    }
}

